# How to use key from the keyof as key for another type?

Tags: typescript

For example there function and its interface:

```js
interface A {
  book: string;
  math: number;
}

function test(name: keyof A, value: A[typeof name]) {}
```

then

```js
test('book', 2); // is valid
test('math', 'str'); // is valid
```

How to set the second parameter type to depend from the first parameter value?

```js
test('book', 2); // is invalid
test('math', 'str'); // is invalid

test('book', 'str'); // is valid
test('math', 2); // is valid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell TypeScript about your constraint by using a type parameter.

```
function test<K extends keyof A>(name: K, value: A[K]) {}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIEYD2BA1gFzIDOYUoA5gNw7IC2cYAFuSAK7N7SMAvliwxuIBGGAEQySFQA8AaWQQAHpBAATCsmIQAngRhoAfAAoQcZhHJKANMgBucADbdbaANpKAugEpMYSx5MHMAckIScMcAJn96ZAB6JORgXVAXV2AtEIgqCNYOGORwqihwhOTU9LSQLJyRUIio4hKy6krElLTdBtzm8KL2Evjumr63HKA).

The difference is, in the above definition we're using exactly the same key in both places. It can be either `book` twice or `math` — twice.

In your original code, `keyof A` denotes one of two. Then, `typeof name` points to the same thing — `keyof A` — which is a union of `book` or `math`. It means 4 combinations are allowed, because there are two degrees of freedom.